# I/O error when passing command line argument to a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have written a one-liner bash script(`bright.sh`) to manually adjust the display brightness.

`sudo sh -c 'echo "$1" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'`

Here I take the brightness value from the terminal and pass it as an argument to the echo command. But on running the script, I get an I/O error as follows:

`sh: echo: I/O error`

What do I do in order to pass the argument successfully from the terminal and control the brightness manually?
An example usage might look like:

`./bright.sh 230`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$1` in the `sh -c` script will expand to the first command line argument of *that* script, not to the first command line argument of the calling script (since the `sh -c` script is single quoted).

The correct solution is not to inject the value of `$1` from the calling script into the `sudo` script (this would allow for various interesting code injection vulnerabilities), but to pass `$1` from the outer script to the inner:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness' sh "$1"
```

Alternatively, use `sudo tee` to write to the file as root:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness >/dev/null
```

If the data printed to the file is always an integer, use `%d` as the `printf` format placeholder instead of `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that by putting `$1` outside the single inverted comma. Not sure if this is the best approach.

The working script now looks like-

`sudo sh -c 'echo '$1' > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you see the problem (your answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481424/4778), but you still must quote the `$1` (just in case).
And don't forget to specify the interpreter (`#!…`)

«solution removed, as it does not quote properly, and has a security bug. see @Kusalananda answer.»

We can concatenate strings by touching them together. Double quotes will expand $ expressions, but single will not. In this case you could have put it all in a double quote, as the rest of the text has no `$`s, so it makes no difference.